# ExtJS in rtl have problems in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, extjs

I've made a site with openlayers and Ext 4.2 and when changed it to rtl the map is broken only in chrome.

The wierd thing is that when I put the EXACT same code in fiddle , the map loads fine.

here is a link to my site (problem in chrome only)

```
http://77.235.53.170/LehavimExt/
```

And here is example to the JSFiddle which DOES work in chrome (maybe because of fiddle CSS?)

http://jsfiddle.net/uvY3r/

This is the problem I'm having:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to add the following style to the openlayers container

```
"width":"100%","position":"relative"
```